# How to access static property of constructor in java-script using instance variable of constructor?

Tags: javascript

I have created a class(constructor) in java-script as given below which has a property of type static.

```
function MyClass(property1 )
{
    this.Property1 = property1 || "";
}

MyClass.StaticProperty = {
    Running: "Running",
    NotRunning: "NotRunning"
}
```

Now I can access the above static property using constructor name as below:

```
MyClass.StaticProperty.Running
```

But I also want to access the property using an instance of the constructor as below:

```
var myClassInstance = new MyClass("value");
var status = myClassInstance.StaticProperty.Running;
```

*I am aware that I can access if it is a **prototype variable or variable defined inside the constructor**. But I don't want to do that because I want it to **behave as a static variable**.*

**Use case:**

I am having multiple constructors with the same property name. I am getting these constructor instances in the array. I want to loop through each constructor in an array and read the static variable. For example

```
var allStaticPropertyValues = [];
for(index = 0; index < arrayOfConstructors.length; index++)
{
    for(var property in arrayOfConstructors[index].StaticProperty)
    {
        allStaticPropertyValues.push(arrayOfConstructors[index].StaticProperty[property]);
    }
}
```

**What I tried:**

1. I tried to get class Type using ***typeof*** keyword but it is giving only as an object, not constructor reference that I can use to access the property.
2. ***instanceOfObject.constructor.getname()*** which will give the name of the constructor as a string and not as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `constructor` property of instance of the `MyClass` to get `MyClass` and then you can access the static variables of `MyClass`

```js
function MyClass(property1 )
{
    this.Property1 = property1 || "";
}

MyClass.StaticProperty = {
    Running: "Running",
    NotRunning: "NotRunning"
}

var myClassInstance = new MyClass("value");
var status = myClassInstance.constructor.StaticProperty.Running;

console.log(status)
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the `constructor` property will give you a *direct* reference to the constructor (the object, not as a string), so you can then just access its `StaticProperty` property:

```js
function MyClass(property1 ){
    this.Property1 = property1 || "";
}
MyClass.StaticProperty = {
    Running: "Running",
    NotRunning: "NotRunning"
}
var myClassInstance = new MyClass("value");


var status = myClassInstance.constructor.StaticProperty.Running;
console.log(status);
```